# Join pandas DataFrame values by closest index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a fast and good practice to join [pandas `DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) values by it's closest index ? I have to do this for big dataframes and my hacks and work arounds I have tried, are slow and therefore not very usefull.

Lets say I have two dataframes `df` and `df2`. Now I want to join the values of `df2` into `df`, regarding to it's closest/nearest index.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(4, 6)), 
                index=[1,1.55,3.33,9.88], 
                columns=[1,2.66,4.66,8.33,11.11,12])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(2, 3)), 
                index=[1.51,3.31], 
                columns=[2.64,4.65,8.31])

In [23]: df
Out[23]:

         1.00   2.66   4.66   8.33   11.11  12.00
1.00     98     40     28     36     49     92
1.55     52     51     61     64     28     98
3.33     66     33     91     21     24     79
9.88     30     21     13     62     89     22

In [24]: df2
Out[24]:

      2.64  4.65  11.12
1.51   999   999   999
3.31   999   999   999

# The result should look like the following:

         1.00   2.66   4.66   8.33   11.11  12.00
1.00     98     40     28     36     49     92
1.55     52     999    999    55     999    98
3.33     66     999    999    67     999    79
9.88     30     21     13     62     89     22
```

Comment: How do you define "close"?  Are we talking "The price is right" rules?  or Euclidean distance? or ....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***setup***
because OP dataframes were inconsistent

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    1,
    index=[1,1.55,3.33,9.88],
    columns=[1,2.66,4.66,8.33,11.11,12])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    999,
    index=[1.51,3.31],
    columns=[2.64,4.65,8.31])

print(df)

      1.00   2.66   4.66   8.33   11.11  12.00
1.00      1      1      1      1      1      1
1.55      1      1      1      1      1      1
3.33      1      1      1      1      1      1
9.88      1      1      1      1      1      1

print(df2)

      2.64  4.65  8.31
1.51   999   999   999
3.31   999   999   999
```

Trickiness I don't have time to explain.  [Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)

```
kw = dict(method='nearest', tolerance=.3)
df2.reindex(df.index, **kw).T.reindex(df.columns, **kw).T.combine_first(df)

      1.00   2.66   4.66   8.33   11.11  12.00
1.00    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
1.55    1.0  999.0  999.0  999.0    1.0    1.0
3.33    1.0  999.0  999.0  999.0    1.0    1.0
9.88    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
```

---

I'd have rather done this

```
df2.stack().reindex_like(df.stack(), **kw)
```

But I got:

> NotImplementedError: method='nearest' not implemented yet for MultiIndex; see GitHub issue 9365

At least it'll be available at some point in the future.

Comment: Very interesting about using tolerance with reindex.

Comment: What a great solution! Thank you for your brilliant expertise! It does exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @Manuel glad I could help.